# Not able to fetch the price from search result of Booking.com

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate the following scenario:

1. Go to Booking.com
2. Select Pune in Destination, checkin-checkout date, adult=3 and click on search page
3. Fetch all properties from all pages(1 to n) along with price and print them
4. Now print property name and price where price is between 3k to 5k

I am stuck at step 3.
I am able to fetch all property results but not their prices as some properties don't have price.
Please find my code below:

```
package automation_project_test;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SearchProperties extends BaseClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        launch_Browser();
        searchProperties();
        // close_browser();
    }

    public static void searchProperties() throws InterruptedException {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        // Wait for search field to be clickable
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Where are you going?']")));

        // Enter pune in search field
        WebElement dest = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Where are you going?']"));
        dest.clear();
        dest.sendKeys("Pune");

        // Selecting from auto suggestion
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li")));
        List < WebElement > listofdest = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']/li"));
        for (WebElement e: listofdest) {
            System.out.println(e.getText());
            if (e.getText().contains("Pune")) {
                e.click();
                System.out.println("Pune clicked");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pune not found");
            }
        }

        // Scroll the page
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,550)", "");

        // Work out today and tomorrow
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(today);
        LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1 L);
        System.out.println(tomorrow);

        // Use selectDate method to click on the relevant dates
        selectDate(driver, today);
        selectDate(driver, tomorrow);

        WebElement adult = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='2 adults']"));
        adult.click();
        WebElement incease_adult = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[text()='+'])[position()=1]"));
        incease_adult.click();

        WebElement search_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button[@data-sb-id='main']"));
        search_button.click();

        List < WebElement > pagination = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='bui-pagination__item sr_pagination_item']/a"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        if (pagination.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("pagination exists and size=>" + pagination.size());
            int page_no = pagination.size();
            for (int i = 2; i <= pagination.size(); i++) {

                Thread.sleep(15000);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@role='heading']")));
                List < WebElement > proplist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='hotel_name_link url']/span[1]"));
                for (int j = 0; j < proplist.size(); j++) {
                    System.out.println(j + " " + proplist.get(j).getText());
                }

                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='bui-pagination__item sr_pagination_item']/a")));
                System.out.println("page number: " + i);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='bui-pagination__item sr_pagination_item'][" + i + "]")).click();;
                Thread.sleep(5000); //wait 
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("no pagination");
        }
    }

    private static void selectDate(WebDriver driver, LocalDate date) {
        // Looking at the markup the attribute data-date is formatted as an
        // ISO_LOCAL_DATE
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
        // Programmatically generate dateLocator based on date passed in
        By dateLocator = By.xpath(String.format("//td[@data-date='%s']", formatter.format(date)));
        // Wait for date element to be visible, then click on it
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dateLocator)).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: The XPath to select the prices (from properties who have price) would be : `//div[@class="sr_item_content sr_item_content_slider_wrapper"][.//div[@aria-hidden]]//div[@aria-hidden]` Could you provide an example where a property has no price ? I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: @Sh87 - I wasn't able to find any property that had no price, I have modified your code to an extent and I have also posted the console logs that has the hotel name and price in a legible manner. Please check the code and let me know your thoughts

Comment: @WilfredClement  Thanks for your help. Earlier when I was trying, price is not shown for few properties but now it is available for all properties. Also, thanks for teaching me how to write code in optimized way.

Comment: To complete, you could also use XPath to select directly the properties which respect your price condition. For example :
`//div[@class="sr_item_content sr_item_content_slider_wrapper"][.//div[@aria-hidden][translate(substring(.,6,20),",","")>=3000 and translate(substring(.,6,20),",","")<=5000]]//span[@class="sr-hotel__name"]` will return the list of properties where price is between 3k and 5k.

Comment: @E.Wiest Can you please explain the xpath you have written.

Comment: Property price is stored in an div element (the one with @aria hidden attribute). We extract this value with `substring` function to remove the leading "Rs.". And we remove the coma with `translate` function. So for example, "Rs. 16,800" becomes "16800". With this we can evaluate each div element (div with extracted then transformed value >=3000 <=5000). Once we get the div elements which respect this condition, we look for the element containing the name of the hotel (span).

Comment: Couldn't think of an idea to filter out the hotels under price 3k and 5k but thanks to @E.Wiest comment I was able to come up with something, I have updated the answer with the complete code and have also added another ans below explaining only the part of code that does the filter FYR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look at the code and would like to suggest few modifications

You don't have to code like below

```
dest.clear();
dest.sendKeys("Pune");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li")));
List < WebElement > listofdest = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']/li"));
```

rather,

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Where are you going?']"))).sendKeys("Pune");
List<WebElement> listofdest = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li")));
```

Also, You don't have to scroll the page

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,550)", "");
```

If you are using Chrome then use Chrome Options to maximize the window at the very start

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

or you can always maximize window using below

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

You are also initiating the loop at i=2 and iterating only till 6, you are missing out 2 pages completely

I have made a couple of changes to your code and was able to fetch the hotel names and price list from all 8 pages and write them to the console ( Below is the complete code )

```
public class Stack7 {

static String Final = null;
static ArrayList<String> al;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Link - https://stackoverflow.com/q/61344077/3190953

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Wilfred\\Desktop\\Udemy\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/");

    // Wait for search field and send "Pune"
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Where are you going?']")))
            .sendKeys("Pune");

    // Selecting from auto suggestion

    List<WebElement> listofdest = wait
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li"))); // driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']/li"));
    for (WebElement e : listofdest) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
        if (e.getText().contains("Pune")) {
            e.click();
            System.out.println("Pune clicked");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pune not found");
        }
    }

    // Work out today and tomorrow
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(today);
    LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println(tomorrow);

    // Use selectDate method to click on the relevant dates
    selectDate(driver, today);
    selectDate(driver, tomorrow);

    WebElement adult = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='2 adults']"));
    adult.click();
    WebElement incease_adult = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[text()='+'])[position()=1]"));
    incease_adult.click();

    WebElement search_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button[@data-sb-id='main']"));
    search_button.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<WebElement> pagination = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='bui-pagination__item sr_pagination_item']/a"));
    int page_noa = pagination.size();

    System.out.println(page_noa);

    if (page_noa > 0) {
        System.out.println("pagination exists and size : " + page_noa);
        System.out.println("Page Number : 1");
        for (int i = 1; i <= page_noa + 1; i++) {

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@role='heading']")));
            List<WebElement> HotelName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='hotel_name_link url']/span[1]"));
            List<WebElement> proplista = driver.findElements(
                    By.xpath("//div[@class='bui-price-display__value prco-inline-block-maker-helper']"));
            for (int j = 0; j < HotelName.size(); j++) {

                String Title = "The name of the hotel is " + HotelName.get(j).getText();
                String Amount = "And price is " + proplista.get(j).getText();

//                  String FinalOutput = j+1 + " ) " + Title + " " +Amount;

//                    System.out.println(FinalOutput);

                Final = (Title + " " + Amount);
                System.out.println(Final);

                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\p{Sc}").matcher(Final);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    String trimmed = Final.substring(matcher.end()).trim();
                    int output = Integer.parseInt(trimmed.replace(",", ""));

                    if ((output >= 3000 && output <= 5000)) {
                        answers.add(Final);

                    }

                }

            }

            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='bui-pagination__item sr_pagination_item']/a")));

            int pageNum = i + 1;
            if (pageNum <= page_noa + 1) {
                System.out.println("Page Number : " + pageNum);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='bui-pagination__item sr_pagination_item'][" + i + "]"))
                        .click();
                ;
                Thread.sleep(5000); // wait
            } else {
                System.out.println("All details fetched");
                System.out.println("Below is the list of hotels withing 3k and 5k");
                final String output = String.join("\n", answers);
                System.out.println(output);
            }

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("no pagination");
    }
}

private static void selectDate(WebDriver driver, LocalDate date) {
    // Looking at the markup the attribute data-date is formatted as an
    // ISO_LOCAL_DATE
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    // Programmatically generate dateLocator based on date passed in
    By dateLocator = By.xpath(String.format("//td[@data-date='%s']", formatter.format(date)));
    // Wait for date element to be visible, then click on it
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dateLocator)).click();
}
}
```

Below is the complete console output

> ```
> Pagination Exists and Size : 8
> Page Number : 1
> The name of the hotel is Conrad Pune Koregaon Park by Hilton And price is ? 10,200
> The name of the hotel is Marriott Suites Pune And price is ? 16,800
> The name of the hotel is Royal Orchid Central, Pune And price is ? 5,400
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Studio Estique And price is ? 3,375
> The name of the hotel is Space Butler - Dwarkadhish And price is ? 1,800
> The name of the hotel is Residency Club And price is ? 4,900
> The name of the hotel is FabExpress DDPK Ajay Inn Pune Airport And price is ? 1,609
> The name of the hotel is Icon Bliss by Bird Of Paradise And price is ? 1,980
> The name of the hotel is Hyatt Place Pune Hinjawadi And price is ? 6,400
> The name of the hotel is My Dream House And price is ? 8,000
> The name of the hotel is Gypsy Soul And price is ? 12,500
> The name of the hotel is Amanora Park Town And price is ? 2,600
> The name of the hotel is Treebo Trend Regency And price is ? 1,952
> The name of the hotel is Hyatt Pune And price is ? 8,250
> The name of the hotel is 3 BHK friendly apartment And price is ? 1,650
> The name of the hotel is GOGO PREMIUM POOL PARTY VILLA And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Royal Inn And price is ? 1,199
> The name of the hotel is Weekend Villa And price is ? 2,025
> The name of the hotel is Atithi Inn Guesthouse And price is ? 1,500
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Woodland And price is ? 2,464
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Park And price is ? 1,123
> The name of the hotel is Exotica villa And price is ? 17,099
> The name of the hotel is Casa Boutique Stays And price is ? 2,850
> The name of the hotel is KARYA SUITES And price is ? 1,768
> The name of the hotel is hotel suraj classic And price is ? 1,347
> Page Number : 2
> The name of the hotel is Treebo Trend Luxe Suite And price is ? 2,131
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Cozy Inn And price is ? 3,999
> The name of the hotel is Lemon Tree Hotel Hinjewadi Pune And price is ? 5,662
> The name of the hotel is Seth's Villa And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is JM Four Hotel And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is OYO 72270 Punest Hotel And price is ? 798
> The name of the hotel is OYO 70336 Royal Orbit Blue And price is ? 1,137
> The name of the hotel is The Ambassador Hotel And price is ? 3,450
> The name of the hotel is Advantage 2 U Hospitality Hinjewadi Pune And price is ? 14,600
> The name of the hotel is Royal Orchid Golden Suites And price is ? 3,928
> The name of the hotel is Hyatt Regency Hotel and Serviced Apartments Pune And price is ? 8,750
> The name of the hotel is Mukesh Residency And price is ? 1,560
> The name of the hotel is ANUGRAH BUNGLOW, MALAVALI And price is ? 10,500
> The name of the hotel is Atithi Happy Stays And price is ? 1,800
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Aristro And price is ? 2,199
> The name of the hotel is Ginger Pune - Pimpri And price is ? 3,999
> The name of the hotel is Dhepe wada And price is ? 6,210
> The name of the hotel is Noorya Hometel And price is ? 4,299
> The name of the hotel is LIVING WAYS HOTEL And price is ? 2,240
> The name of the hotel is New Pune Residency And price is ? 1,100
> The name of the hotel is Countryside And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is OYO 69270 Ar Rooms And price is ? 936
> The name of the hotel is 4BHK AC Bunglow Near WET N Joy Water Park And price is ? 10,441
> The name of the hotel is iSuite Hotel Kharadi Pune And price is ? 3,200
> The name of the hotel is Surya Shibir Resort And price is ? 8,844
> Page Number : 3
> The name of the hotel is 5BHK AC Bunglow Near WET N Joy Water Park And price is ? 11,391
> The name of the hotel is Valley View Holiday Villa 4 Beds Suitable For 6 - 30 Pax By Savai And price is ? 15,999
> The name of the hotel is Cozy Nesting And price is ? 1,300
> The name of the hotel is SmartStay And price is ? 2,100
> The name of the hotel is OYO 70948 Sai Vatika And price is ? 1,137
> The name of the hotel is Oakwood Residence Naylor Road Pune And price is ? 7,600
> The name of the hotel is Advantage 2 U Hospitality Corporate Service Apartment Kharadi And price is ? 15,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Bhairavee And price is ? 3,800
> The name of the hotel is VIORICA HOTELS And price is ? 6,500
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Dreamland And price is ? 2,500
> The name of the hotel is OYO 68826 R K Lodging And Amrut Restaurant And price is ? 1,636
> The name of the hotel is Green Shine Farm And price is ? 12,000
> The name of the hotel is Jain Room And price is ? 1,760
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Raviraj And price is ? 2,100
> The name of the hotel is Da Casa Business Hotel And price is ? 1,954
> The name of the hotel is Grand Tamanna Hotel And price is ? 5,400
> The name of the hotel is Homestay in the Heart of the City And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Mindpeace Camping And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Pawna Water and Woods And price is ? 4,500
> The name of the hotel is Ideal Service Apartments And price is ? 5,950
> The name of the hotel is Executive Tamanna Hotel And price is ? 3,700
> The name of the hotel is Hotels Rajgad And Lodging And price is ? 2,500
> The name of the hotel is Hermitage Suites Koregaon Park And price is ? 8,800
> The name of the hotel is BIZZ Tamanna Hotel And price is ? 4,200
> The name of the hotel is TrunkTales 2 And price is ? 1,600
> Page Number : 4
> The name of the hotel is Corporate Stay And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Casa De Spe by Vista Rooms And price is ? 16,000
> The name of the hotel is OYO 71831 Mohan Lodging And price is ? 1,164
> The name of the hotel is SPOT ON 72417 Sk Lodge And price is ? 698
> The name of the hotel is OYO 72593 Adarsh Farm And price is ? 804
> The name of the hotel is OYO 72690 Hotel Rajvilas And price is ? 1,106
> The name of the hotel is SPOT ON 71935 Deepali Garden Lodge And price is ? 700
> The name of the hotel is SPOT ON 68908 Hotel Swaraj And price is ? 700
> The name of the hotel is SPOT ON 71651 Hotel Sr Executive Lodge And price is ? 700
> The name of the hotel is OYO 71465 Gangotri Hill Top Resort And price is ? 1,005
> The name of the hotel is OYO 68503 Asha Inn And price is ? 804
> The name of the hotel is OYO 70002 Hotel Hill View And price is ? 1,008
> The name of the hotel is OYO 69560 Hotel Kaveri Lodge And price is ? 1,137
> The name of the hotel is OYO 67880 Sai Executive And price is ? 1,137
> The name of the hotel is JK Rooms 104 Nr Pune Station And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Platinum Heights Apartments And price is ? 5,200
> The name of the hotel is teak trail And price is ? 3,750
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Swan Inn And price is ? 3,300
> The name of the hotel is Aasra Lodging And price is ? 3,305
> The name of the hotel is Amanora Park Town And price is ? 2,800
> The name of the hotel is Leasurely Abode Service Apartment And price is ? 5,040
> The name of the hotel is Sky High at Blue Ridge 22nd floor And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Jain Home And price is ? 4,752
> The name of the hotel is Behind Pune Airport – Bougainvilla Service Apartment And price is ? 18,300
> The name of the hotel is Jain Boutique Home And price is ? 2,880
> Page Number : 5
> The name of the hotel is MPKSuites Pune And price is ? 2,400
> The name of the hotel is Matoshree lake view proparty lavasa And price is ? 2,000
> The name of the hotel is 3 BHK Apartment Lavasa And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Orritel Convention Spa and Wedding Resort And price is ? 4,400
> The name of the hotel is Devi Residency And price is ? 3,800
> The name of the hotel is Fairfield by Marriott Pune Kharadi And price is ? 7,098
> The name of the hotel is Bed and Breakfast In 5bhk Koregaon Park And price is ? 2,800
> The name of the hotel is JW Marriott Pune And price is ? 17,910
> The name of the hotel is Calypso Suites by Magnus And price is ? 3,400
> The name of the hotel is Holiday Inn Express Pune Hinjewadi And price is ? 5,098
> The name of the hotel is Treebo Trend Niraali Executive And price is ? 2,991
> The name of the hotel is FabExpress DDPK And price is ? 2,863
> The name of the hotel is NP HOSPITALITY BANER And price is ? 2,457
> The name of the hotel is Vosiv Suites And price is ? 3,100
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Stafi And price is ? 1,649
> The name of the hotel is Star Residency by magnus And price is ? 3,200
> The name of the hotel is Destination 41 by bird of paradise And price is ? 4,432
> The name of the hotel is Courtyard by Marriott Pune Hinjewadi And price is ? 9,498
> The name of the hotel is OYO Home 63544 Elegant Stay Model Colony And price is ? 1,700
> The name of the hotel is Tarawade Clarks Inn Pune And price is ? 7,798
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Jagannath And price is ? 3,610
> The name of the hotel is Lemon Tree Hotel Viman Nagar Pune And price is ? 7,349
> The name of the hotel is The Green Gate Resort And price is ? 10,400
> The name of the hotel is OYO Home 62074 Designer Stay Hinjewadi And price is ? 1,501
> The name of the hotel is Smart Inn And price is ? 2,847
> Page Number : 6
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Kohinoor Executive And price is ? 5,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Suyash Deluxe And price is ? 4,200
> The name of the hotel is Randeep Lodge And price is ? 2,160
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Royal Enclave And price is ? 1,762
> The name of the hotel is Sai Camping Pawana Lake Camping And price is ? 7,200
> The name of the hotel is The Upper Room And price is ? 3,900
> The name of the hotel is OYO Home 67371 Royal Bliss Near NIBM And price is ? 1,501
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Poonam And price is ? 3,186
> The name of the hotel is umbrella service apartments And price is ? 5,000
> The name of the hotel is Orbett Hotel And price is ? 7,500
> The name of the hotel is FabExpress ABC Inn And price is ? 3,986
> The name of the hotel is Royce Studio Apartments And price is ? 2,998
> The name of the hotel is Elegant Stay in Baner And price is ? 2,237
> The name of the hotel is Deluxe One Bedroom home, away from home in Pune And price is ? 2,906
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Bhola And price is ? 5,184
> The name of the hotel is Deluxe Room in Apartment And price is ? 4,810
> The name of the hotel is Treebo Trend Lotus And price is ? 3,627
> The name of the hotel is Elegant Home Studio in Porvorim, Goa And price is ? 9,416
> The name of the hotel is TSquare MPKSuites And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Ritz And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Sorina Hillside Resort And price is ? 6,000
> The name of the hotel is Amanora Service Apartment And price is ? 3,700
> The name of the hotel is OYO Home 46551 Alluring Stay Pimpri And price is ? 1,901
> The name of the hotel is Ginger Pune - Wakad And price is ? 4,898
> The name of the hotel is Corporate Luxury Stays Magarpatta Pune And price is ? 4,408
> Page Number : 7
> The name of the hotel is Yogisthaan And price is ? 3,500
> The name of the hotel is Collection O 30016 Citiotel Shivajinagar And price is ? 11,175
> The name of the hotel is Comfort Service Apartments And price is ? 4,500
> The name of the hotel is HMR Hotels - HMR Royal Inn And price is ? 2,468
> The name of the hotel is Home From Home And price is ? 3,998
> The name of the hotel is Four Points By Sheraton Hotel and Serviced Apartments And price is ? 8,998
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Indraprasta ( Sharanam ) And price is ? 3,692
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL FLYING INN Airport Road And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Gogas Island And price is ? 3,013
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Chandan Residency And price is ? 2,700
> The name of the hotel is The Samrat Hotel near Pune Railway Station And price is ? 4,598
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Eco Inn Viman Nagar And price is ? 3,078
> The name of the hotel is OM Hospitality And price is ? 4,500
> The name of the hotel is Pawna Lake Star Camping And price is ? 5,800
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Orchard And price is ? 5,500
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Sunshine And price is ? 7,214
> The name of the hotel is Niva Stays Prime And price is ? 2,903
> The name of the hotel is Iprass Corporate Service Apartments Baner And price is ? 4,900
> The name of the hotel is Veridical Hospitality, Baner - Pune And price is ? 3,280
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Tushar And price is ? 3,050
> The name of the hotel is Rohini Home Stay And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Royal Residency And price is ? 2,699
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Staywel And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is DOVES INN And price is ? 4,750
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Grandeur And price is ? 4,898
> Page Number : 8
> The name of the hotel is Kyriad Hotel Chinchwad And price is ? 7,700
> The name of the hotel is The Ritz-Carlton, Pune And price is ? 19,700
> The name of the hotel is Gunjan lakeside homestay, Panshet And price is ? 6,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Crystal And price is ? 5,500
> The name of the hotel is Palm Royale And price is ? 3,500
> The name of the hotel is Rutugandh Heritage And price is ? 3,500
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Nandanvan Annexe And price is ? 3,850
> The name of the hotel is Urban inn And price is ? 4,375
> The name of the hotel is Bauhinia And price is ? 5,824
> The name of the hotel is Maitri Pawana Lake campaigning And price is ? 6,000
> The name of the hotel is Lake View Resort Khadakwasala And price is ? 1,998
> The name of the hotel is Fantasy Land Camping And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Emerald Vista Luxury Suites And price is ? 5,400
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Pavitra And price is ? 2,598
> The name of the hotel is A.R.H HOSPITALITY And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Ratwa Resort Bhimashankar And price is ? 2,850
> The name of the hotel is Aerith Studios by bird of paradise And price is ? 6,000
> The name of the hotel is Shree Sadgurukripa And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Swaroop Hotel And price is ? 4,940
> The name of the hotel is AR Suites Fontana Bay And price is ? 9,444
> The name of the hotel is Sanket Inn And price is ? 7,000
> The name of the hotel is The Sirona Hotel And price is ? 6,500
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL ALPINE And price is ? 3,135
> The name of the hotel is Nest by StayBird And price is ? 2,100
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL SHREE EXEQUTIVE And price is ? 2,998
> Page Number : 9
> The name of the hotel is Shau Resorts and Banquets And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Shree Panchratna Pune And price is ? 5,700
> The name of the hotel is Malhar Machi A Mountain Resort And price is ? 34,200
> The name of the hotel is The Grand Tulip And price is ? 5,678
> The name of the hotel is Kalpatharuvu-KNY Service Apartments And price is ? 4,598
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Sunderban Resort & Spa And price is ? 9,000
> The name of the hotel is Lakeventure And price is ? 3,900
> The name of the hotel is Valley camping And price is ? 3,300
> The name of the hotel is Saee Farm Stay And price is ? 1,350
> The name of the hotel is Bombay Backpackers Pune And price is ? 600
> The name of the hotel is Backpackers Hive And price is ? 1,533
> The name of the hotel is Jugglers Backpack And price is ? 1,200
> The name of the hotel is Niva Stays Airscape And price is ? 3,300
> The name of the hotel is OYO Home 70067 Peaceful Stay Swargate And price is ? 1,500
> The name of the hotel is Niva Stays Paradise And price is ? 4,200
> The name of the hotel is URBAN NOMADS And price is ? 1,830
> The name of the hotel is OYO 68474 Hotel Viraj And price is ? 5,862
> The name of the hotel is Ashirwad Guest House (Male Only) And price is ? 1,800
> The name of the hotel is Backpacker's Island And price is ? 1,797
> The name of the hotel is Andharban Home Stay And price is ? 3,150
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL CORPORATE GUESTLINE And price is ? 4,500
> All details fetched
> Below is the list of hotels withing 3k and 5k
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Studio Estique And price is ? 3,375
> The name of the hotel is Residency Club And price is ? 4,900
> The name of the hotel is GOGO PREMIUM POOL PARTY VILLA And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Cozy Inn And price is ? 3,999
> The name of the hotel is Seth's Villa And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is JM Four Hotel And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is The Ambassador Hotel And price is ? 3,450
> The name of the hotel is Royal Orchid Golden Suites And price is ? 3,928
> The name of the hotel is Ginger Pune - Pimpri And price is ? 3,999
> The name of the hotel is Noorya Hometel And price is ? 4,299
> The name of the hotel is Countryside And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is iSuite Hotel Kharadi Pune And price is ? 3,200
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Bhairavee And price is ? 3,800
> The name of the hotel is Homestay in the Heart of the City And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Mindpeace Camping And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Pawna Water and Woods And price is ? 4,500
> The name of the hotel is Executive Tamanna Hotel And price is ? 3,700
> The name of the hotel is BIZZ Tamanna Hotel And price is ? 4,200
> The name of the hotel is Corporate Stay And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is JK Rooms 104 Nr Pune Station And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is teak trail And price is ? 3,750
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Swan Inn And price is ? 3,300
> The name of the hotel is Aasra Lodging And price is ? 3,305
> The name of the hotel is Sky High at Blue Ridge 22nd floor And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Jain Home And price is ? 4,752
> The name of the hotel is 3 BHK Apartment Lavasa And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Orritel Convention Spa and Wedding Resort And price is ? 4,400
> The name of the hotel is Devi Residency And price is ? 3,800
> The name of the hotel is Calypso Suites by Magnus And price is ? 3,400
> The name of the hotel is Vosiv Suites And price is ? 3,100
> The name of the hotel is Star Residency by magnus And price is ? 3,200
> The name of the hotel is Destination 41 by bird of paradise And price is ? 4,432
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Jagannath And price is ? 3,610
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Kohinoor Executive And price is ? 5,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Suyash Deluxe And price is ? 4,200
> The name of the hotel is The Upper Room And price is ? 3,900
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Poonam And price is ? 3,186
> The name of the hotel is umbrella service apartments And price is ? 5,000
> The name of the hotel is FabExpress ABC Inn And price is ? 3,986
> The name of the hotel is Deluxe Room in Apartment And price is ? 4,810
> The name of the hotel is Treebo Trend Lotus And price is ? 3,627
> The name of the hotel is TSquare MPKSuites And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Ritz And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Amanora Service Apartment And price is ? 3,700
> The name of the hotel is Ginger Pune - Wakad And price is ? 4,898
> The name of the hotel is Corporate Luxury Stays Magarpatta Pune And price is ? 4,408
> The name of the hotel is Yogisthaan And price is ? 3,500
> The name of the hotel is Comfort Service Apartments And price is ? 4,500
> The name of the hotel is Home From Home And price is ? 3,998
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Indraprasta ( Sharanam ) And price is ? 3,692
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL FLYING INN Airport Road And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Gogas Island And price is ? 3,013
> The name of the hotel is The Samrat Hotel near Pune Railway Station And price is ? 4,598
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Eco Inn Viman Nagar And price is ? 3,078
> The name of the hotel is OM Hospitality And price is ? 4,500
> The name of the hotel is Iprass Corporate Service Apartments Baner And price is ? 4,900
> The name of the hotel is Veridical Hospitality, Baner - Pune And price is ? 3,280
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Tushar And price is ? 3,050
> The name of the hotel is Rohini Home Stay And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Staywel And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is DOVES INN And price is ? 4,750
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Grandeur And price is ? 4,898
> The name of the hotel is Palm Royale And price is ? 3,500
> The name of the hotel is Rutugandh Heritage And price is ? 3,500
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Nandanvan Annexe And price is ? 3,850
> The name of the hotel is Urban inn And price is ? 4,375
> The name of the hotel is Fantasy Land Camping And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is A.R.H HOSPITALITY And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Shree Sadgurukripa And price is ? 3,000
> The name of the hotel is Swaroop Hotel And price is ? 4,940
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL ALPINE And price is ? 3,135
> The name of the hotel is Shau Resorts and Banquets And price is ? 3,600
> The name of the hotel is Kalpatharuvu-KNY Service Apartments And price is ? 4,598
> The name of the hotel is Lakeventure And price is ? 3,900
> The name of the hotel is Valley camping And price is ? 3,300
> The name of the hotel is Niva Stays Airscape And price is ? 3,300
> The name of the hotel is Niva Stays Paradise And price is ? 4,200
> The name of the hotel is Andharban Home Stay And price is ? 3,150
> The name of the hotel is HOTEL CORPORATE GUESTLINE And price is ? 4,500
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I have made few changes to the code and have updated the answer on top, the below is what I have done

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\p{Sc}").matcher(Final);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                      String trimmed = Final.substring(matcher.end()).trim();
                      int output = Integer.parseInt(trimmed.replace(",", ""));

                      if ((output >= 3000 && output <= 5000)) {
                            answers.add(Final);
                        }
                    }
```

Added a pattern match on the final string that we print, split only the text after the match criteria, convert that into an integer, use an if case and store the output into an arrayList

```
    List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Print it at the end after printing all the values

```
System.out.println("All details fetched");
System.out.println("Below is the list of hotels withing 3k and 5k");
final String output = String.join("\n", answers);
System.out.println(output);
```

**Snippet :**

> ```
> Below is the list of hotels withing 3k and 5k
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Studio Estique And price is ? 3,375
> The name of the hotel is Residency Club And price is ? 4,900
> The name of the hotel is GOGO PREMIUM POOL PARTY VILLA And price is ? 4,000
> The name of the hotel is Hotel Cozy Inn And price is ? 3,999
> The name of the hotel is Seth's Villa And price is ? 4,000
> ```